# Connecting to Oracle from Java ...Exception

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to connect Remote Oracle DB but I have Exception. Help me please.
What can I do?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
   try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****:1521/******", "*********",
                    "********");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterSetMetaData$JdbcCharacterSetMetaData.isFixedWidth(CharacterSetMetaData.java:1292)
        at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterSetMetaData.getRatio(CharacterSetMetaData.java:1230)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.init(DBConversion.java:159)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.<init>(DBConversion.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1075)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Comment: Try to post all your code

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****:1521:******", "*********",
                    "********"); ................remove "/" and put ":"

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using and what version of Oracle are you connecting to?

Comment: I using  ojdbc6. And test it in other jdbc drivers

Comment: Check if your database version is supported by the driver version you are using. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/index-099369.html. Take the latest version from the posted link. After some more investigation it might be an encoding problem.

Comment: Could you enable the logging to see if there would be some more information. See the **edit2** in my answer.

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov Have a look the my updated answer.

Comment: ojdbc6 is not a version, it indicates the driver is for Java 6. Please specify your oracle version and your driver version.

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov Has this problem been solved? If so, please post for other reader what solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your connect URL is wrong formatted. You are mixing the `SID` and `service` format.

Either

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:<user>/<password>@<host>:<port>:<sid>");
```

or

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid>", "<user>", "<password>");
```

or in case you connect to a service instead of a SID

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:<user>/<password>@//<host>:<port>/<service");
```

For an example using a `Properties` object have a look into the [javadoc of oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)

**edit** Find here the link to the [Thin-style Service Name Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA)

**edit 2** Enable driver logging to see if there would be some helpful message there.

```
OracleLog.setTrace(true);
DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

**edit 3** Here a way to find via reflection which charset is reported by the server and driver.

For permission reason the package declaration is important.

```
package oracle.jdbc.driver;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import oracle.sql.CharacterSet;
import sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory;

public class OJdbcInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OracleLog.setTrace(true);
        DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));

        System.out.printf("defaultCharset: %s%n", Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.printf("file.encoding : %s%n", 
            System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

        String connectUrl = 
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:<user>/<password>@<host>:<port>:<sid>";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectUrl)) {
            T4CConnection t4Conn = (T4CConnection) con;
            T4C8TTIpro pro = t4Conn.pro;

            short oVersion = pro.oVersion;
            short svrCharSet = pro.svrCharSet;
            short driverCharSet;
            try {
                driverCharSet = DBConversion.findDriverCharSet(
                    svrCharSet, oVersion);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.err.printf("failed to get driver charset: %s%n", 
                    e.getMessage());
                driverCharSet = -1;
            }

            System.out.println("server charset: " + svrCharSet);
            System.out.println("driver charset: " + driverCharSet);

            Object instance = ReflectionFactory.getReflectionFactory()
                    .newConstructorForSerialization(
                            Class.forName("oracle.sql.CharacterSetFactoryThin"),
                            Object.class.getConstructor())
                    .newInstance();

            for (Field fs : CharacterSet.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (fs.getType() == short.class) {
                    if (fs.getShort(instance) == driverCharSet) {
                        System.out.printf("charset name  : %s%n", fs.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

compile

```
mkdir bin
javac -cp ojdbc6_g.jar -d bin/ OJdbcInfo.java
```

run

```
java -cp ojdbc6_g.jar:bin/ oracle.jdbc.driver.OJdbcInfo
```

possible output

```
defaultCharset: UTF-8
file.encoding : UTF-8
server charset: 873
driver charset: 873
charset name  : AL32UTF8_CHARSET
```

Most probably the driver charset is `-1` in your case.

Check that you are using an up-to-date driver version.

```
java -jar ojdbc6.jar
```

possible output

```
Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Thu_Jul_03_18:17:32_PDT_2014
```

Check the `locale` setting on your Linux box

```
locale
```

possible output (depends on your language setting, but all values should be normally the same)

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But I have already tried it, and the problem isn't related to your explanation.

Comment: But Class T4CConnection and T4C8TTIpro isn't public how can I call them?

Comment: Thank you for response.Yes problem in this. In my  Oracle Parametrs my NLS_CHARACTERSET not AL32UTF8. How can show in program my NLS_CHARACTERSET?

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov To answer your question regarding `T4C8TTI`: `For permission reason the package declaration is important.`

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov Regarding `NLS_CHARACTERSET`, I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do. Something like `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER like '%CHARACTERSET'`?

Comment: This query return me value where NLS_CHARACTERSET=AZ8ISO8859P9E. Thus reason, I can not connect to the database. How can I show in Java code that my NLS_CHARACTERSET is AZ8ISO8859P9E not AL32UTF8.

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov Which specific database/ojdbc/java/OS are you using? If you are using an ojdbc version before `ojdbc6.jar` you might need the `orai18n.jar`.

Comment: Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 / ojdbc6.jar / Java 1.8/ CentOS

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov Have a look to my updated answer (code snippet amended and some checks for the locale added). Verify your locale settings. Post the output in your question. If all still looks valid you should call the Oracle service.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code you are using

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid>", "<user>", "<password>");
```

So remove `/` between `<port>/<sid>` and put `:` between `<port>:<sid>`

> Your updated code will be
>
> ```
> Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
>                     "jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****:1521:******", "*********",
>                     "********");
> ```

and for further details you can refer this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12137/getconn.htm#TDPJD136

I hope, It will help you.

Comment: Thank you for response.I did  it But is not the problem. If I have problem in code i don't think that Exception be "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov, Can you trace error or exception in fullstacktrace or log file, then update only that piece of code where you are getting exception.

Comment: Exception in Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****:1521:******", "*********",
                    "********"); level